# how to merge two unequal dataframes based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge two dataframe.

dataframe 1:

```
Name  Early   Mid   Late    AverageS   Date   Place    Rno   Num   Bar
xyz    32.0  12.2    32       76     20190202   NY      1     4     2
abc    46.0  24.2    96       67     20190802   SA      2     6     2
ghj    29.0  85.2    34       35     20190211   PY      3     2     7
yui.   9.0    5.2    4         5     20191105   AU      4     1     9
......
```

dataframe 2:

```
Name   Date     Place    Rno   Num   Bar   Finish Position   
xyz    20190202   NY      1     4     2         1
ghj    20190211   PY      3     2     7         4
abc    20190802   SA      2     6     2         2

......
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
Name  Early   Mid   Late    AverageS   Date   Place    Rno   Num   Bar   Finish Position 
xyz    32.0  12.2    32       76     20190202   NY      1     4     2         1
abc    46.0  24.2    96       67     20190802   SA      2     6     2         2
ghj    29.0  85.2    34       35     20190211   PY      3     2     7         4
yui   9.0    5.2    4         5     20191105   AU      4     1     9          NAN
......
```

i tried this but the 'finish position' values are all chnaged to NAN in merged df.

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='left', on=['Name','Bar','Rno','Place','Date','Num'])
```

Comment: Based on the code , there does not seem be any issues there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vaebhav mentioned in the comment section, your code is correct.

I replicated your process and got the following dataframe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRgeI.png

Which is what you were looking for.

I would suggest at this point to check if one of the data frames is somehow not parsed correctly.

Please share some more information regarding how the two DFs were constructed.

Comment: I have uploaded the og dataframes

Comment: Hi @zee, I think the problem lays in the structure of DataFrame 2. 
Can you please check if column ['Finish Position']  is not separated to two columns after the merge. I recopied your table, then I found the ['Finish Position'] is parsed as two columns ['Finish'] with the data and ['Position'] with NULLs. 
Can you please verify that? I would suggest to generally to avoid column names with spaces. try using "_" or CamelCase instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dataframe2 does not have a row where [Name] is "yui", so it displays as "NaN".

And I see that the row in dataframe1 is displayed as "yui.", maybe just "yui." does not match "yui".

Comment: The dataframes are unequal but they def have some same values. I checked them manually